# Nav dropdown menu issues

Tags: html, css, nav, html.dropdownlistfor

Having some trouble with my nav, i'm trying to create a dropdown menu when you hover over the "Match" link. every time I hover the mouse over the link, list will stay underneath said link and disrupt how the navigation bar looks. Any helps will be much appreciated

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <span class= "navbar-button"></span>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Match</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">City</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Coastal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rural</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: 'main';
}

.navbar {
list-style: none;
background-color: #333;
color: #fff;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar > li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 1.3% 2%;

}

.navbar > li:hover {
background-color: #585858;

}

.navbar > li > a{
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 30px;
color: #fff;

}

.navbar li ul {
display: none;
}

.navbar li:hover ul{
display: block;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `absolute` positioning to break it out of the container so it won't disrupt the rest of the elements:

```
.navbar li ul {
  position: absolute; 
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Be sure to set its parent to `position: relative` or the `body` will become its container:

```
.navbar > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.3% 2%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5r4zq4cv/)

Answer (score 0):

Add position absolute to: .navbar li ul